# Use Robot Framework logging file at the end of test case execution

Tags: python, robotframework

I am a new Robot Framework user and have a question regarding the log file that it makes at the end of executing testcases. I would like to use the html file it creates and upload it automatically to the correct ticket. I already have python code that works to upload the file and it can be used as a keyword, but I am not sure how I can call upon that keyword as a test teardown step as at that point the logging probably is not created yet..

Is this correct and if so: is there another way to automatically call a python function to upload the html file after executing a testcase?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use things as below:

```
Test Teardown    Run keyword if test Passed/Failed   Name_of_kw
```

Add this to your settings section of .robot file.

Now, define the kw: (Import Process Library first in your robot file)

```
Name_of_kw
Start Process <tab>  python <tab> path_to_file.py<tab> alias=prog
Wait for Process  prog  #wait until it gets completed
Get Process Result prog    stdout=yes #to make sure you have uploaded it
```

================
more details at -https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#library-documentation-top

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help :) 
I tried your solution and it runs correctly as in it doesn't give error messages, but the logging file does not get uploaded unfortunately. I also see that the log file from robot framework gets created after the test has passed (including running the teardown). so maybe there is nothing uploaded because the log file doesn't yet exist when executing the teardown?

Comment: @Anna. you can add a separate case for this to be executed at the end of suite.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem and I've got an alternative solution for getting log files (log.html, report.html, output.xml) in same execution and upload them to a FTP Server.

I created a python script in Robot Framework's root project folder:

```
import subprocess
import os.path
import time

arguments = sys.argv
subprocess.run(arguments)
logs = ['log.html', 'report.html', 'output.xml']

while not os.path.exists(logs[0] and logs[1] and logs[2]):
  time.sleep(1)

do_something()
```

**Instead of running:**

```
robot .\tests\...\suite
```

**Run:**

```
python script.py robot .\tests\...\suite
```

In that way, you will be able to work with output files when tests or suites are finished.

If you run robot's command with **-d flag** to save results on a different folder, consider using automatic variable from Robot Framework called **${OUTPUT DIR}** to get full source path and save it to txt file on root folder. That's because you'll be able to read it and find the logs in your script.py.